# If $g(x) < 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$ exist, does this mean that $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) < 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to solve this question with this steps:

- $g(x)<0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
- $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) < \lim_{x\to 0}0$
- $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) < 0$

Then this means that it is true but the answers bring by the teacher says it is false. Could you help me find my mistake please?

Comment: the mistake you are making is in the second line. that line is not true

Comment: If you imposse the aditional hypothesis that $g$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ then is true that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} g(x)<0$. But as @angryavian showed in the answer down here, your proof is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(x) = \begin{cases}-|x| & x \ne 0 \\ -1 & x = 0\end{cases}$.

Then $g(x) < 0$ for all $x$, but  $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0$.

---

Your mistake is that $f(x) < g(x)$ will only imply $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \le \lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$; counterexamples like the one above are one way to demonstrate why you can't keep the strict inequality in the limit.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $g:\Bbb R \to \mathcal G$ for some set $\mathcal G$. Intuitively, one would think that $\lim_{x\to\alpha}g(x)\in\mathcal G$ for each $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, but this is not quite the case. Instead, we have that $$\forall\alpha\in\Bbb R;\ \lim_{x\to\alpha} g(x)\in\bar{\mathcal G}$$
where $\bar{\mathcal G}$ represents the *closure* of $\mathcal G$ (the smallest closed set containing it). If $\mathcal G$ is *open*, that means it doesn't contain its boundary points, but its closure *does*. For example, $\mathcal G=(0,1)$ contains neither $0$ nor $1$, but $\bar{\mathcal G}=[0,1]$ contains both. Hence, you can find functions with range $(0,1)$ that have $0$ or $1$ as limits. (If $f:(1,\infty)\to(0,1); f(x)=1-\frac1x$, then $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=0, \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$)

In this question, we are considering $\mathcal G=\Bbb R^-$, the negative real numbers. Its closure is simply $\Bbb R^-_0$, the non-positive real numbers.

Because of this, you can find a function with limit $0$. angryavian's answer does so.